# Adding JButtons to a JPanel via a for loop

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have a List of Customer Objects. I want to create JButtons for each object in the List. 
This is the code i have so far,

```
public class Customer_List extends javax.swing.JFrame {

List<Customers> cus_list = new ArrayList();

public Customer_List() {

    cus_list = showCustomers();
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    displayCustomers();
    initComponents(); 
}

public void displayCustomers(){
    JButton[] buttons  = new JButton[cus_list.size()];
    System.out.println(cus_list.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < cus_list.size(); i++){
       buttons[i] = new JButton();
       buttons[i].setText(cus_list.get(i).getName());
     contentPane.add(buttons[i]);
    }
   add(contentPane);
   contentPane.validate();
}
```

I'm fairly new to swing. When i run this, the JPanel shows up but without the buttons. If i remove the initcomponents() method, the button shows up but no JPanel. What am i doing wrong?
This is the content of the initcomponent method,

```
  private void initComponents() {

    contentPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    contentPane.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Customer List"));
    contentPane.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));

    jLabel1.setText("Customer List");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout contentPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout);
    contentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(190, 190, 190)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(233, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    contentPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(452, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(contentPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(contentPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

`

Comment: What is the content of `initComponents ()` method? How `showCustomers ()` method is able to return a list of some `Customers`, since you need an object of this class, in order to provide a list of `Customers`. Look closely to the first line of `initComponents ()` method, `contentPane` is being reinitialized there.

Comment: It is a auto generated method from netbeans, ill update the question with the content of it.

Comment: the `showCustomers()` is a webservice, it properly returns the list, i tested it out. Because this works properly when i remove the `initcomponents()` method

Comment: And i can't modify the content of the `initcomponents()` method. That part is blocked out.

Comment: Try to remove line `contentPane = new JPanel();` and move `displayCustomers ();` as the last line of `Customer_List` constructor. And replace `contentPane.validate ();` with `contentPane.revalidate (); contentPane.repaint ();` inside `displayCustomers ()`.

Comment: Still no buttons are displayed. :/

Comment: Also remove `add(contentPane);` from `displayCustomers ()` method, since `contentPane` has been added via `layout.setHorizontalGroup( layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)   .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(contentPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));` this call inside `initComponents ()` method

Comment: Still nothing, the JPanel and everything gets displayed, no buttons :/